# When I send post request in vue.js it generates get request

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The code is as simple as

```
this.$http.post(url, data);
```

On local machine it generates `POST` request.

On cloud server it generates `GET` request.

Version of vue.js is the same.

Comment: Sorry this is not enough information.

Comment: Agreed. Please post code of the actual AJAX request as well as your server-side route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On localhost request to `/example/url/` is processed without redirect but on server request to `/example/url/` makes redirect to `/example/url` (without trailing slash). Because of this `POST` becomes `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same problem. try to use `[HttpPost]` attribute in the controller along with the attribute you are using.